# How can I get info-boxes to appear outside of the map div using Bing Maps 7.0?

Tags: javascript, maps, bing

The effect I'm looking for is demonstrated at:

http://demo.maps101.com/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&view=items&cid=6:interactive-maps&id=12068:us-state-capitals&Itemid=7

This is easy enough to do with Bing Maps 6.3 by adding a description to a pin, however this functionality seems to have been removed in version 7.0.  Version 7 has a fairly nice info-box mechanism which I've employed successfully, but the info-boxes it creates are added as children of the map div, not the body element like in the example.  Since the map-div has the CSS property *overflow: hidden* the info-boxes get cut off by the edge of the map.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FnWLT/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple, but time consuming answer is to create your own infobox I recommend this as a starting point from which you can customize the behaviour to your requirements:

http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Infobox%20Control

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this, but it's been a long time with no other answers so I'll go with this one.